# .bat file to search for pst files

Tags: file, batch-file, find, pst

Can anyone help me with a (simple as possible) batch file I can unleash on a users profile to search for PST files.
I would need to see the location of any PST files that were found.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About as simple as it gets :)

```
dir C:\*.pst /s /b
```

Comment: No worries bud. If this answered your question you can accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Variable %USERPROFILE% gives the profile directory of currently logged in user. You can use the DIR command to list all the *.PST files recursively under that. The simplest script would be

```
ECHO using directory %USERPROFILE%

DIR /B /P /S %USERPROFILE%\*.PST
```

You can change the switches of DIR command to format the output.